# Interpreting thermal shutdown threshold values from TPS659037

Tags: pmic

I'm studying the datasheet of TI [TPS659037](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/TPS659037/datasheet/device-overview-slis165224#SLIS165224) PMIC. The MIN / TYP / MAX values are throwing me off here. Are these 3 numbers indicating variations between every IC manufactured?

[image: da]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these 3 numbers indicating variations between every IC
> manufactured?

Yes.  You can think of the MIN and MAX as guaranteed, but the vast majority of devices will be closer to the TYP value.

Answer (score 0):

If the temperatures are specified at a FIXED AMBIENT temperature, then YES, those are production/test variations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the statistical spread of the Thermal Shutdown Thresholds across all devices. So the guarantee is that no device will have a Rising Threshold of less than 133 Celsius and more than 163 Celsius, but mostly at 148 Celsius, and so on ... Typical values would be average accross devices at the quoted temperature.